# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'make' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\qrcodesau.py", line 1, in 
import qrcode
File "D:\Python\qrcode.py", line 3, in 
im=qrcode.make(url)
^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'make' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: You have probably named your own script `qrcode.py`, so *that's* what's being found by `import qrcode` rather than the actual module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tonight I had the same issue (received the exact same error), and the problem was I had named my program qrcode.py. I was using the sample code found at https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/

```
import qrcode
img = qrcode.make('Some data here')
type(img)  # qrcode.image.pil.PilImage
img.save("some_file.png")
```

I was stumped for a bit never having seen this error before.  When I found the reply above ... ohhhh.  Of course.